# Is Poly1305 enough for cascading ciphers?

Tags: hmac, mac, integrity, poly1305

ChaCha20 along with Poly1305 provides confidentiality and integrity. Now suppose I cascade AES on top of ChaCha20. Is it safe to assume that the Poly1305 MAC is still secure, even if I cascade multiple ciphers? In other words, is one MAC enough to secure both ChaCha20 and AES?

**Problem solved:** [Is Poly1305 an information-theoretically secure MAC?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/48416/54184)

Comment: Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/48416/54184. But basically yes.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Question solved. I'll add the link to my question.

Comment: Here I marked it as a duplicate for you so you can accept the duplicate link.